# wmi query fails for remote machine if asynchronus mode is selected

Tags: wmi, wmi-query, wmi-service, wbem

I am trying to execute wmi query (**select * from win32_ntlogevent**) in **remote machine** using wbemtest.
It is successful in semi-synchronous mode.
if **asynchronous mode** is selected, the query fails and returns an error message, which shows **Access is Denied**.

can anyone explain why this is happening ??

Comment: try to run it as administrator